# testing for differences using jackknife distributions

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, resampling, jackknife, subsampling

I have two distributions relative to two experimental conditions.

I compute a certain index (i.e. coherence) describing each distribution.

I want to see if there is a significant difference between the indexes of the two distributions.

But now I have one value per distribution.

Therefore I am using the jackknife approach to re-calculate two distributions of my indexes and check for statistical significance.

Q: Now **i have two jackknife distributions, how can i actually see if they are significantly different**?

1. Can I just do a t-test between the two jackknife distributions?
2. Do I have to "manipulate" my data before performing any test? the variance of my jackknife distributions is suspiciously low!

Thank you for your time.

Valerio

Comment: I think you may be looking for either a permutation test or bootstrapping but from your description I cannot be sure.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. In my case I am reluctant in getting data from other distributions (permutation?), and I don´t have enough samples to get random subsamples (bootstrapping?) of my dataset. I think the leave 1 out strategy is good enough to get a distribution back.

Comment: the question is, what do i do with the output of the jackknife?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify, but let's assume you used delete-1-jackknife.

#### Problem statemement

In that case, you have for each deletion $n$ **unique** Jackknife samples with the $i$th sample vector being
$$X_i = \{X_1, X_2, X_3,..., X_n-1, X_n\}$$

You estimate your parameter with $ s(\cdot) $ which returns

$$ \hat\theta_i = s(X_i) $$

> It seems to me that you are stuck with a vector $\hat\theta$ with $i$ entries. I assume you want to estimate the location parameters of two independent samples, and test whether they are significantly different?

To do so, you need to calculate the variance $V$ as
$$V_{\theta} = \frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\hat\theta_i - \bar\theta)^2$$
with
$$ \bar\theta = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \hat\theta_i$$

#### Conclusion

To answer your two questions directly:

> Can I just do a t-test between the two jackknife distributions?

No

> Do I have to "manipulate" my data before performing any test? the variance of my jackknife distributions is suspiciously low!

Note the difference in the factor for estimating $V$. Instead of $\frac{1}{n}$, you use $\frac{n-1}{n}$. Imagine it as a correction factor to account for the repetition of samples within $X$.

#### Possible Solutions

After you have calculated $V_{\theta}$ and $\bar\theta$ from $X$, you can contrast it against the output from another independent sample, e.g. $V_{\beta}$ and $\bar\beta$ from $B$.

Your statistical test-value $Q$ could then be calculated as $$ Q = \frac{\bar\theta-\bar\beta}{\sqrt{V_{\theta}+V_{\beta}}}$$ You can derive your critical values for $Q$ from a normal distribution to reject $H_0$ if $Q \geq z_\alpha$ with $z_\alpha$ being the upper $\alpha$th percentile.

A sensible alternative is bootstrapping, as it allows you to estimate the confidence bounds of the difference directly without any recurse to a parametric distribution.

*References*

See also Hollander, Wolfe (1999): Nonparametric statistical methods. Wiley